# Routing between wifi and ethernet is extremely slow on home router,

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet, nas

I have home Zyxel router, that serves as WiFi AP, DHCP server and has Ethernet ports. On one of Ethernet ports I have NAS connected. When I connect my PC to other Ethernet port routing between Ethernet ports works well, but when I connect over WiFi, the WiFi-to-Ethernet routing is extremely slow (like 1kbps). DHCP works well, all devices including NAS get IP address correctly assigned, so I think there is no IP conflict.

Do you have any advice how to configure WiFi-to-Ethernet routing so it works normally? It doesn't matter if I run Windows or Linux or Mac OS on the Wifi connected PC, and it doesn't matter what protocol I use. All are very slow, SMB, AFP, NFS. I also tried to use Raspberry Pi with WiFi and Ethernet and port routing worked well there, but I'd prefer to use the Zyxel router to connect to NAS.

I used iperf. It confirms what I suspect - there is initial transfer, which then stalls after few kB. It looks like some buffer problem:

```
sudo iperf -c 10.0.0.10 -r -t 20 -i 2
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 10.0.0.10, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 10.0.0.11 port 35158 connected with 10.0.0.10 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0- 2.0 sec   301 KBytes  1.23 Mbits/sec
[  4]  2.0- 4.0 sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec
[  4]  4.0- 6.0 sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec
[  4]  6.0- 8.0 sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec
[  4]  8.0-10.0 sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec
[  4] 10.0-12.0 sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec
[  4] 12.0-14.0 sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec
[  4] 14.0-16.0 sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec
[  4] 16.0-18.0 sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec
[  4] 18.0-20.0 sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec
[  4]  0.0-20.5 sec   301 KBytes   120 Kbits/sec
```

At that point the iperf client stalls, looks like never getting a response and not responding to Ctrl-C (in Linux)

Comment: Could be an issue with the wireless RF environment. Download a Wi-Fi analysis app such as WiFiMan from Ubiquiti Networks and look at the channels that are in use.

Comment: Can you run iperf between a wireless device and a LAN Ethernet device (preferably a Mac or PC with gigabit ethernet)? Measuring each direction independently would be helpful. Note that iperf sends from client to server by default.

Comment: Also, are you routing (ie engaging the CPU to push packets),  or bridging (which can be offloaded with a lot less CPU).   Routing means that IP addresses are in different ranges, bridging implies IP addresses are in the same range.

Comment: Hi sorry for wrong terminology. I am bridging - all devices including router have IP in range 10.0.0.x

Comment: I used iperf. It confirms what I suspect - there is initial transfer, which then stalls after few kB. It looks like some buffer problem: